# ¿Cómo ordenar meses de forma ascendente?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo la siguiente consulta y me muestra los meses ordenados ascendentemente (Abril, Febrero, Diciembre, etc), pero quiero que mande (Enero, Febrero, Marzo, etc)

```
select COUNT(Id_S) [Quantity], DATENAME(MM, S.Date) [Birthdate]
from student S
group by DATENAME(MM, S.Date) 
order by DATENAME(MM, S.Date)
```

Comment: ¿En qué motor de bases de datos quieres hacer esto?

Comment: En SQL Server @Alfabravo

Comment: Para tus preguntas, procura incluir la etiqueta correspondiente. Si lo crees relevante, puedes incluso elegir la etiqueta para la versión que estás usando.

Answer (score 3):

Como tienes el `order`, el mismo será alfabético, simplemente ordena los resultados por el número de mes mediante [`DATEPART()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) que retorna el valor numérico.

```
select COUNT(Id_S) [Quantity], DATENAME(MM, S.Date) [Birthdate]
       from student S
       group by DATENAME(MM, S.Date), DATEPART(MM, S.Date) 
       order by DATEPART(MM, S.Date)
```

Comment: Necesitas también agrupar por `DATEPART( MM, S.Date)`

Comment: Gracias @LuisCazares, es cierto